# NMAP running on Zenmap 7.93 NSOCK ERROR ssl_init_helper OpenSSL legacy provider failed to load

Tags: openssl, nmap

I installed the latest version of Zenmap 7.93 that calls Nmap on Windows 11.
I also installed the latest version of OpenSSL 1.1.1.q.
However, when I launch Zenmap and conducted an Intense Scan:

```
nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.1.12
```

The following Message was displayed at the top of Zenmap:

```
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-09-10 07:29 Eastern Daylight Time

NSOCK ERROR [0.4770s] ssl_init_helper(): OpenSSL legacy provider failed to load.
```

I searched Google for this error as well as this platform and could not find any solution to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution now is to uninstall nmap version 7.93 and reinstall 7.92.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in nmap 7.93. Try installing version 7.92 and see.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this Issue over Github https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2532.

This has been fixed in commit https://github.com/nmap/nmap/commit/9d0e5ac2b915c5e90568200a58fb98c44aec961d however a new release is yet to be tagged.

Answer (score 1):

[Zen]Nmap version 7.94 is out and the fix for this issue has been included.